# Conditional Formatting with Time through Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to **highlight the time based on the folowing rules**

If the time is lower than 7:30 be closer to red

Otherwise if the time is closer to 8:05 get close to green

In this sheet:

[image]

I guess it's easier to explain with the following illustration:

[image]

You should get the basic idea of what I'm trying to accomplish with the formulars in the formatting rule picture. That one however doesn't work.

Any ideas what would be the proper way to format this rule?

Comment: Hi, its the < and > that are the errors. Change them to = and your Formula works.

Comment: @DanH.Unfortunately it doesn't. I did try that, before I put the <> signs in formula and didn't work either.

Comment: What is the error/warning indicated by the green triangle in the top left of each "worktime" cell?  If it says "Number stored as text" then that's your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the left side for value write `0,31` and on the right side write `0,34`.

To get the correct value, that is corresponding to the correct time, simply select the time in Excel, using the `Time()` formula, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and select `Number`. You will see the correct number for the time.

Answer (score 0):

Also found a way, albeit this is more of a workaround:

You can enter the values as a raw number in format of AB:CD:EF (or depending on the time format you are using) and excel will automatically format the rule somehow with decimal signs, although this really is more of a workaround rather than answer to the actual question

Answer (score 0):

You can use "industrial minutes", minutes to a base of 100 industrialseconds. Then you can use standard decimal values.
In excel you simple multiply time values by 24 to get to that. Then 30 minutes are 0.5 of an hour.

[image]

For the conditional formating use a 3-Color scale and set the middlepoint to number 7.5 and a lighter green.